# scrollTop or scrollLeft on horizontal website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a website I am working on (here is a basic [example](https://codepen.io/caitlinmooneyx/pen/xvgBvY)), yesterday I got some help to implement active states on the radio-style button navigation, and I am now trying to link this up so that it also changes on page scroll/when in view as currently it's only onClick.

I roughly know how to achieve this as I've done something similar before, but then it occurred to me that because the page and scrollbar are rotated to accommodate the horizontal effect, I don't know if it would now be scrollTop or scrollLeft. I've never used scrollLeft before so I am unsure how to use it correctly. I am wondering if anyone has implemented something similar before and what the correct way would be? I've tried both and nothing seems to be working. [This](https://jsfiddle.net/5xx6g7j8/4/) is what I'm roughly trying to achieve (but only one class active at a time).

I thought maybe using Waypoints could be another option, but again it's hard to find anything online which explains how this works when a site is rotated multiple times.

My JS knowledge is shaky (still learning!), I'm only trying to implement what I think would work so this is probably not even correct, any help understanding what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated!

[Heres the latest thing I've tried.](https://codepen.io/caitlinmooneyx/pen/xvgBvY)

```js
// --- change span classes on click 

const setIconState = (icon, state) => icon.className = state
    ? icon.className.replace('button-off', 'button-on')
    : icon.className.replace('button-on', 'button-off')

const toggleIcon = element => {
  const className = element.className;
  element.className = className.indexOf('button-on') > -1
    ? setIconState(element, false)
    : setIconState(element, true);
}

const setIconActiveState = (icon, state) => icon.className = state
  ? icon.className = `${icon.className} active`
  : icon.className = icon.className.replace('active', '')

document.querySelectorAll('.bottomnav span.icon')
  .forEach(icon => {
    icon.onclick = (e) => {
      const {
        target: clickedSpan
      } = e;
      
      const siblings = [...clickedSpan.parentElement.parentElement.querySelectorAll('span.icon')]
        .filter(sibling => sibling != clickedSpan);

      siblings.forEach(icon => {
        setIconState(icon, false);
        setIconActiveState(icon, false);
      });
      setIconState(clickedSpan, true);
      setIconActiveState(clickedSpan, true);
    };
  });
  
// --- change span classes on scroll test

function onScroll(event){
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('.bottomnav a').each(function () {
        var currLink = $(this);
        var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
        if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
            $('.bottomnav a span').removeClass("active");
            currLink.addClass("active");
        }
        else{
            currLink.removeClass("active");
        }
    });
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
    color: #000;
    font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 7px;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.bottomnav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}

.bottomnav span {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #888;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 26px;
}

.bottomnav span:hover {
    color: #fac123;
}

.bottomnav span.active {
    color: #fac123;
}

#container {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100vh);
    transform-origin: top left;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vh;
    height: 100vw;
    white-space: nowrap;
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

#container .card {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: inline-flex;
    position: relative;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
}

#player {
    transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100vh);
    transform-origin: top left;
    font-size: 0;
    width: 100vh;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    /*        position: absolute;*/
}

#player section > object {
    width: 100vw;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}


section object > div {
    white-space: normal;
}

.container::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

section {
      padding: 5%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    position: relative;
    transition: .5s ease;
}

.cardwhite {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.cardblack {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: 'IBM Plex Serif', sans-serif;
}

p {
    font-size: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.5.5/dist/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="bottomnav" id="bottomnav">
            <a href="#1"><span class="icon ion-ios-radio-button-on active"></span></a>
            <a href="#2"><span class="icon ion-ios-radio-button-off"></span></a>
            <a href="#3"><span class="icon ion-ios-radio-button-off"></span></a>
        </div>

<div class="container" id="container">
        <div id="player">
       <section class="card cardwhite" id="1">
                <object>
                        <h2>Section 1</h2>
                        <p>Description</p>
                  
                </object>
            </section>

    <section class="card cardblack" id="2">
                <object>
                        <h2>Section 2</h2>
                        <p>Description</p>
                    
                </object>
            </section>

    <section class="card cardwhite" id="3">
                <object>
                        <h2>Section 3</h2>
                        <p>Description</p>
                 
                </object>
            </section>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would it be easier to just make a page that's 300% of the width of the screen that you offset with margin-left? Then you can just use a transition on that to create the scrolling effect when switching page. I think it would allow you to get rid of alot of CSS code and the JS calculation, simplifying everything.

Comment: Tried that originally and it messed everything up. It feels too hacky to me. I'm happy with the layout and how it functions, I'm just not good at calculating how the scroll should work based on the prior rotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For horizontal scrolling I would go the following route, simplifying your HTML and whaty you listen for. Since touch devices can easily just swipe to scroll, all you need to do is make it accessible for people with scroll wheels. You could also add an animation, but it makes this snippet too long.

```js
const main = document.querySelector( 'main' );
const nav = document.querySelector( 'nav' );

let scrollend;

function onwheel(){
  
  /* When using the scrollwheel, translate Y direction scrolls to X direction. This way scrollwheel users get the benefit of scrolling down to go right, while touch and other users get default behaviour. */
  
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  
  main.scrollLeft += event.wheelDeltaY;
  
}
function onscroll(){
  
  /* When scrolling, find the nearest element to the center of the screen. Then find the link in the nav that links to it and activate it while deactivating all others. */
  
  const current = Array.from( main.children ).find(child => {
  
      return child.offsetLeft >= main.scrollLeft - innerWidth / 2;
      
  });
  const link = Array.from( nav.children ).reduce((find, child) => {
    
    child.classList.remove( 'selected' );
    
    return find || (child.href.indexOf( current.id ) >= 0 ? child : find);
    
  }, false);
  
  if( link ) link.classList.add( 'selected' );
  
  clearTimeout( scrollend );
  scrollend = setTimeout( onscrollend, 100 );
  
}
function onscrollend(){
  
  /* After scrolling ends, snap the appropriate element. This could be done with an animation. */
  clearTimeout( scrollend );
  
  const current = Array.from( main.children ).find(child => {
  
      return child.offsetLeft >= main.scrollLeft - innerWidth / 2;
      
  });
  
  main.scrollLeft = current.offsetLeft;
  
}

/* Bind and initial call */

main.addEventListener( 'wheel', onwheel );
main.addEventListener( 'scroll', onscroll );

onscroll();
```

```css
html,
body,
main {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
main {
    display: flex;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    scroll-snap-type: x proximity;
}
main section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
}
nav {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
nav a {
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    margin: 1em;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
nav a.selected {
    background: black;
}

.bland { background: gray; }
.dark { background: darkgray; color: white; }
.bright { background: yellow; }
```

```html
<nav>
  
  <a href="#section-1">Section 1</a>
  <a href="#section-2">Section 2</a>
  <a href="#section-3">Section 3</a>
  
</nav>

<main>
   
   <section class="bright" id="section-1">
      <h2>Section 1</h2>
   </section>
   
   <section class="dark" id="section-2">
      <h2>Section 2</h2>
   </section>
   
   <section class="bland" id="section-3">
      <h2>Section 3</h2>
   </section>
  
</main>
```

Comment: This is what I am trying to achieve, however as my website utilises a vertical-to-horizontal scroll this would not work, my scroll bar is technically at the top of the page. There may be parts of this that could help me though, but wouldn't function as the page and scrollbar are rotated.

Comment: I think that building a site with rotations is going to make your job a lot more difficult - also notice that this technique only applies to the wrapping `main` element, so anything below it would still function as expected. II feel that rotating and then using scrollTop will just cause loads of confusion in your code and it will be hard to manage in the long run.

Comment: Probably, but it's not an overly complex website, the rotations already work correctly as you can see from the Snippet/CodePen. I tried other methods of achieving this beforehand and they weren't as functional, so this is what worked for me. Its cleaner than having an overly wide page, and having to work out calculations for everything. I'm just having trouble thinking how the scroll will work. I think its scrollTop though as the scrollbar is technically moving that direction.

Comment: On mobile I will correct this so that it returns to a real horizontal scroll and users will be able to swipe naturally. On desktop its more natural to scroll vertically so it made more sense. Its just nice to have some input in the hope something will click!

Comment: But both can be accomplished easily - on mobile it will be touch, so the wheel event will remain untriggered. If you change `main { flex-direction:column } ` for mobile you get best of both world and reduced complexity. Rotations shouldnt be used for change a page - they will make your life hard, I promise.

Comment: I understand and appreciate that, but I am yet to find a non-hacky way to achieve a vertical-to-horizontal scroll in pure CSS (JS didn't work either), which also allows snap-scroll. I am yet to run into any major issues, but will keep it in mind.

Comment: I've been playing around with this more this afternoon and its working well so far! Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, I would also prefer a design that does not flip the X and Y axis.
Doing so might bite us in the future, when we try to include non-trivial content on our pages.
Also if we don't do that axis flip, we have no need at all to do positional calculations.

So both the HTML structure and the CSS will be simpler.

AFAIK, it's not possible to do the scrolling purely in non-hacky CSS.

```js
/**
 * Change icon state on click.
 */
const icons = Array.from( document.querySelectorAll( '.icon' ));
const toggleIcon = icon => {
  icon.classList.toggle( 'ion-ios-radio-button-on' );
  icon.classList.toggle( 'ion-ios-radio-button-off' );
};
const clickIcon = event => {
  // toggle previous active state
  toggleIcon( document.querySelector( 'i.ion-ios-radio-button-on' ));
  // toggle own state
  toggleIcon( event.target );
};
icons.forEach( icon => icon.addEventListener( 'click', clickIcon ));
/**
 * Scroll horizontally on scroll wheel.
 * The combination of "scroll-behavior: smooth;" and the "<a href=#>" anchor links,
 * can be reused to do and endless snapping cycle on wheel event.
 */
let scroll_state = 0;
window.addEventListener( 'wheel', event => {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    // cast to -1 or +1
    const offset = event.deltaY / Math.abs( event.deltaY );
    scroll_state += offset;
    // Arrays are zero-based.
    // So if the length matches our state, restart over from the first page.
    if ( scroll_state === icons.length ) scroll_state = 0;
    else if ( scroll_state < 0 ) scroll_state = icons.length - 1;
    // scrolll_state will now always contain the next icon to click.
    icons[ scroll_state ].click();
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
body {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 100%;
}
main {
  display: block;
  height: 90vh;
  width: 300vw;
}
nav {
  background-color: orange;
  display: block;
  height: 10vh;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.page {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 50px;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.5.5/dist/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<body>
  <main>
    <section class="page" id="myapp_first">
      <h1>First</h1>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </section>
    <section class="page" id="myapp_second">
      <h1>Second</h1>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </section>
    <section class="page" id="myapp_third">
      <h1>Third</h1>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </section>
  </main>
  <nav id="myapp_navigation">
    <a href="#myapp_first">
      <i class="icon ion-ios-radio-button-on active"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#myapp_second">
      <i class="icon ion-ios-radio-button-off"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#myapp_third">
      <i class="icon ion-ios-radio-button-off"></i>
    </a>
  </nav>
</body>
```

By leveraging the click event of the icons, we get the icons changing class and the transition for free. Adding more pages now just becomes adding the correct HTML and updating the width of the `<main>` element.

A last thing I would personally add, is a debounce function around the wheel event, so we don't try to scroll faster than we can render.

Without debouncing, we might want to merge the functions so we can include the class changing inside the animationFrame for hopefully less yanky visuals, but that would complicate the click events again, so i'd prefer debouncing the wheel handler.

```js
/**
 * Change icon state on click.
 */
const icons = Array.from( document.querySelectorAll( '.icon' ));
const toggleIcon = icon => {
  icon.classList.toggle( 'ion-ios-radio-button-on' );
  icon.classList.toggle( 'ion-ios-radio-button-off' );
  icon.classList.toggle( 'active' );
};
const clickIcon = event => {
  // toggle previous active state
  toggleIcon( document.querySelector( '.ion-ios-radio-button-on' ));// toggle own state
  toggleIcon( event.target );
};
icons.forEach( icon => icon.addEventListener( 'click', clickIcon ));
/**
 * Scroll horizontally on scroll wheel.
 * The combination of "scroll-behavior: smooth;" and the "<a href=#>" anchor links,
 * can be reused to do and endless snapping cycle on wheel event.
 */
let scroll_state = 0;
window.addEventListener( 'wheel', event => {
  // ANimation frame to smooth out the transition.
  window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    // cast to -1 or +1
    const offset = event.deltaY / Math.abs( event.deltaY );
    scroll_state += offset;
    // Arrays are zero-based.
    // So if the length matches our state, restart over from the first page.
    if ( scroll_state === icons.length ) scroll_state = 0;
    else if ( scroll_state < 0 ) scroll_state = icons.length - 1;
    // scrolll_state will now always contain the next icon to click.
    icons[ scroll_state ].click();
  });
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
    color: #000;
    font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100; /* EDIT: font-weight: 100 basically equals no font weight at all */
    font-size: 7px; /* EDIT: Why so small ? */
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    height: 100vh; /* EDIT: add height, so we can scale off this */
    width: 100vw; /* EDIT: add width, so we can scale off this */
}
.bottomnav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    /*
    overflow: hidden;
    */
    position: fixed;
    /*bottom: 0px; EDIT: not needed after we place the nav at the bottom */
    height: 15vh; /* EDIT: .bottomnav height + #container height = 100vh */
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: black;
}
.bottomnav span {
    /*float: left; /*  why float when flex lets us position exactly? */
    display: block;
    color: #888;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 26px;
}
.bottomnav span:hover {
    color: #fac123;
}

.bottomnav span.active {
    color: #fac123;
}

#container {
    /*
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100vh);
    transform-origin: top left;
    position: absolute;
    */
    width: 300vw; /* EDIT: 300vw, 100 per page of 100vw */
    height: 85vh; /* EDIT: .bottomnav height + #container height = 100vh */
    /*scroll-snap-type: y mandatory; EDIT: only needed if we use snappoints */ 
}
/* EDIT: .card and section are the same elements, merged rule "container" here */
.card {
    width: 100vw; /* EDIT: 100vw for each page of 100vw width */
    height: 100%; /* EDIT: 100% so it scales with the container, not the screen */
    display: inline-block; /* EDIT: block level, since we do not need to flex these */
    float: left; /* EDIT: float left so our pages leave no space between them so 300vw = 100+100+100 . THis can be done with flexbox or grid as well, but is more complicated than needed */
    /*position: relative; EDIT: not needed */
    /* scroll-snap-align: start; EDIT: only needed if we use snappoints */
    padding: 50px;
    /* EDIT:
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    position: relative;
    */
    /* transition: .5s ease; EDIT: I would think that "scroll-behavior: smooth;" already does this */
}
/* EDIT: Since there's no use for the extra wrapper element, positioning it absolute + flex only harms us instead of helping
#player {
    transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100vh);
    transform-origin: top left;
    font-size: 0;
    width: 100vh;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
}
#player section > object {
    width: 100vw;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
*/
/* EDIT: I don't see any <div>s inside the objects
section object > div {
    white-space: normal;
}
*/
/* EDIT: ? Attempt to remove vertical scroll? Not needed
.container::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
*/
.cardwhite {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.cardblack {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: 'IBM Plex Serif', sans-serif;
}

p {
    font-size: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.5.5/dist/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="container">
  <!-- the extra player <div> is useless since the cards fully overlap it.
   so it can be removed -->
  <section class="card cardwhite" id="1">
    <object>
      <h2>Section 1</h2>
      <p>Description</p>
    </object>
  </section>
  <section class="card cardblack" id="2">
    <object>
      <h2>Section 2</h2>
      <p>Description</p>
    </object>
  </section>
  <section class="card cardwhite" id="3">
    <object>
      <h2>Section 3</h2>
      <p>Description</p>
    </object>
  </section>
</div>
<!-- EDIT: Put the nav at the bottom so we do not have position issues -->
<div class="bottomnav" id="bottomnav">
  <a href="#1">
    <span class="icon ion-ios-radio-button-on active"></span>
  </a>
  <a href="#2">
    <span class="icon ion-ios-radio-button-off"></span>
  </a>
  <a href="#3">
    <span class="icon ion-ios-radio-button-off"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I like how this works, it's a shame it's a little glitchy and has some errors. I think theres some useful code there that I can work from though, it's the closest I've been all day to achieving this. I appreciate all the explanation too, it helps me understand a bit more. It took me a long time to get the horizontal scroll working, I'm trying not to mess with it too much.

Comment: Adding a debounce function will fix that sometimes the radios scroll faster than the page. I also did not style the radios, so they're hard to click in this example. What errors should still be fixed?

Comment: The code snippet has Cannot Read errors for 'click'. I am playing around with what you have written on my CopePen (https://codepen.io/caitlinmooneyx/pen/xvgBvY), and it's working once or twice then stops. Getting closer however!

Comment: It's due to the absolute positioning and transformation on the `#container element. A position absolute removes the element from the normal flow, so the browser cannot calculate how much room it needs. If i remove those from the container, you see that it works vertically. But to get it to work horizontally then, you need to put the pages next to each other, instead of underneath, so the scrollbar is in the correct position and such.

Comment: I tried to implement that a moment ago using what you had done, but it just aligns the sections vertically. I will keep trying.

Comment: Yeah, Your positions are fighting your flexbox which is fighting your flaots and position absolute, hence all the yank. Also, we need to flip vh and vw again everywhere. And place the nav underneath and such. So there';s a bunch of rules we should not sue at the same time. Trying to see what can be done.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get it kind of working, but it's still glitchy, and not as smooth as it was before.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a reworked version of your html and css, including annotations. Getting close. Only thing I haven't fixed yet, is the scrollbar no longer appears for manual scrolling. But that'll have to wait.

Comment: Getting there, the code still gives an error when you run the snippet, and the icons glitch. Have a look at the updated CodePen (https://codepen.io/caitlinmooneyx/pen/xvgBvY), I have sorted the scrollbar issue (although it is scrolling the wrong way), but my icons are now gone as the JS has been condensed. Trying to figure out how to reinstate the active icons.

Comment: I still don't get any console errors, so cannot really see that one. I opted for the click version of the JS, since the yank and wrong direction and such is caused by the interaction between scrollLeft and then the click to center around the element. Hence instead of smooth scroll done by the browser, the code tries to do this manually, and then tells the browser to do the same thing, causing the screen to either speed up or snap back depending on how far you scrolled. So if you don't scroll far enough, you snap back to the page you just came from. Hence I don't like this version of the JS.

Comment: I managed to get it mostly working now on my CodePen! With no errors, now I just have to change the radio buttons as it moves! Thanks for your help and information.